# Database login errors in SharePoint event viewer

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-on-prem

We are seeing the below error message in SharePoint server event viewer frequently.

> "Event ID: 3355 Cannot connect to SQL Server - "ServerName" not found.
>   Additional error information from SQL Server is included below
>
> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  This failure occurred while
>   attempting to connect to the Failover server.  The duration spent
>   while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]
>   initialization=2; handshake=1558;[Login] initialization=0;
>   authentication=1; [Post|-Login] complete=10015;"

At the time of the above event viewer error logged, we are seeing below SharePoint hive log.

> An error occured while scanning the database, SP2013_Config, for index
>   fragmentation:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand
>   command)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health.DatabasesAreFragmented.Repair()
>   ClientConnectionId:ad765270-1d33-41cc-8331-af8d9c584cec  Error
>   Number:-2,State:0,Class:11 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   Server: gcmsql03.krys-global.com StackTrace:   at onetnative.dll:
>   (sig=1f46c434-d820-4a5c-8550-b0e8d8318fcd|2|onetnative.pdb,
>   offset=28EE2)  at onetnative.dll: (offset=15735)

"User Profile Synchronization service" service account has write permissions on all the databases.

What else could cause this errors?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following part of the StackTrace could be interesting:
`Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health.DatabasesAreFragmented.Repair()`

Looks like the [`Databases used by SharePoint have fragmented indices`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805067(v=office.14).aspx) TimerJob is failing.

This...
`An error occured while scanning the database, SP2013_Config, for index fragmentation`
And this...
`This failure occurred while attempting to connect to the Failover server.`

... brings me to the following conclusion:

- You have (or had?) configured a [SQL Server Database Mirroring Setup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SharePoint was also configured](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207314(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_2) to be aware of that Mirroring.
- Now for whatever reason, the Timer-Job tries to connect to the Failover-Server. This connect fails.
- Further thinking:

  - Do you still have a DB-Mirroring Setup? Check that setup with your Database Administrator (or ask for more help on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com))
  - Check SharePoint Database-Configuration with the following PowerShell: `Get-SpDatabase | select name,legacydatabaseconnectionstring,failoverserver | Out-GridView`
  - I think you will find some mismatches between configuration in SQL-Server and SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I ran the above PowerShell command and see the connection string for all content databases.
Where can I find the SQL-Server configurations so I can understand the mismatches?